# How to add a chatbot avatar for the chatbot in salesforce ? Apart from creating a VF page?

Tags: community, chat

[image]
[image]
I want to have a chatbot avatar for my chatbot in salesforce community Is there any possibity to add that in configuration settings. I have done it using by creating a new VF page. But the VF page which I have created doesn't fit exactly how the Embedded snapin component in the community. Can any one suggest the best way to add a chatbot avatar.

Comment: if your chat js is  as CDN and is not compatible with locker service, I am worried, that the only option is a Visualforce

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrBerehovskyi . Please look at the screenshots that are attached in the Original post. One with the Avatar is done using the VF Page,but when we keep this in the community we are having a background . Is there any possibility to make this VF function as the original Embedded snap service as the original can hover over the pages in the community.

Answer (score 0):

From the Embedded Service Deployment documentation, there is a setting you can manually add to the code snippet which allows you to specify the avatar for the chatbot in conversations. I've not tried to use this with Community deployments, so I don't know for sure that it would work, but if you haven't it might be worth a try.

```
// This is a custom-set parameter that specifies the avatar image of the Einstein Chatbot
embedded_svc.settings.chatbotAvatarImgURL = "[image url]"
```

Source documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=snapins_chat_parameters.htm&type=5